# Destructuring assignment: order of parameters that depend on each other

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I thought that destructuring was performed after all the parameters were retrieved, however I noticed that this code works.

```js
function extract(propertyName, { [propertyName]: value }) {
  console.log(propertyName, value);
}

extract('property', { property: 'value' });
```

While this one doesn't.

```js
function extract({ [propertyName]: value }, propertyName) {
  console.log(propertyName, value);
}

extract({ property: 'value' }, 'property');
```

Which invalidates my initial thought, but I can't find any documentation or specification that explains the precise behavior.

Comment: Isn't this standard processing order, L->R? http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter values are determined *in order*, very much as though you wrote each parameter as its own `let` declaration taking the value from the actual arguments received. (That **isn't** how it actually works, that's just an analogy.)

So your first example conceptually behaves like this:

```
// ONLY CONCEPTUAL
function extract() {
    let propertyName = /*...the first actual argument...*/;
    let { [propertyName]: value } = /* ...the second actual argument... */;
    console.log(propertyName, value);
}
```

Whereas your second one behaves like this:

```
// ONLY CONCEPTUAL
function extract() {
    let { [propertyName]: value } = /* ...the first actual argument... */;
    let propertyName = /*...the second actual argument...*/;
    console.log(propertyName, value);
}
```

...and so it tries to use the value of `propertyName` before the "variable" is initialized, getting an error. (Because parameter expressions were added in ES2015, so `let` rather than `var` semantics were used for them.)

Another way to look at it is that if you think of the entire parameter list as the contents of iterator destructuring, it works exactly the same way. Thinking of it that way, your first example is:

```
//  v−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v−−−−− iterable destructuring
let [propertyName, { [propertyName]: value }] = /* an iterable for the actual arguments */;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− parameter list
```

This is covered in the specification in the [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) and [IteratorBindingInitialization](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization) sections.

Note that this doesn't really have anything to do with destructuring, just how parameter values are assigned to parameters when the function code is run. For instance, if you try to use a later parameter name in the default value expression of an earlier one, it'll fail for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if that's about to change? It would be pretty nice to have a smarter behavior that would resolve the resolvable parameters first, then the others.

Comment: @GuerricP - I haven't heard anything about changing it, though I'm a couple of months out of date. I'd be really shocked if it changed.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this in quite a lot of detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, including this concept that you can think of the parameter list as the contents of an iterable destructuring pattern. Links in my profile if you're interested.